# Better way to extract mac address and nic name from a file(awk)

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a text `mytest.txt` file whose content is

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:a6:4c:35", ATTR{type}=="1", PROGRAM="/lib/udev/rename_device", NAME="eth0"`

I want to extract the mac address and nic name from the above. I have a very crude way of doing it. Here is what I am doing. Running `cat` and `awk` twice. I am wondering what is a better way of doing this. Also, if there were 2 lines in the file how would I do for both.

```
grep address mytest.txt|awk '{print $4}'
Output
ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:a6:4c:35",
```

```
grep address mytest.txt|awk '{print $7}'
Output
NAME="eth0",
```

How can I do it in a better way where I get the MAC address and name just separated by space. And also, if there are 2 lines in the file, get 2 lines in the output along the lines of

```
<mac1> <nic_name1>
<mac2> <nic_name2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'"' '{print $8,$(NF-1)}' mytest.awk
```

This uses double-quotes mark as delimiter and prints the 8th and the second last fields, the latter retrieved by `$(NF-1)`. `NF` is an awk built-in that contains the number of fields of the current line, so `$NF` is the last field and `$(NF-1)` is the second last field.

Sample output:

```
$ cat file
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:a6:4c:35", ATTR{type}=="1", PROGRAM="/lib/udev/rename_device", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="10:50:56:a6:4c:35", ATTR{type}=="1", PROGRAM="/lib/udev/rename_device", NAME="eth1"
```

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print $8,$(NF-1)}' file
00:50:56:a6:4c:35 eth0
10:50:56:a6:4c:35 eth1
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply. The -F delimiter is `"` I get it. but what is the use of $(NF-1). In short, if you can explain your answer. The answer is certainly working like a charm

Comment: You're welcome! I added an explanation on `$(NF-1)`, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F ',[ \t]*' '{gsub(/(^| )[^=]+=+|"/, ""); print $4, $NF}' file
```

```
00:50:56:a6:4c:35 eth0
```

However if you don't want to hardcode field positions then **better alternative** is this awk that processes each row and populates an array with name-value pairs:

```
awk -F ',[ \t]*|=+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $(i+1));
pair[$i] = $(i+1)}; print pair["ATTR{address}"], pair["NAME"]}' file
```

```
00:50:56:a6:4c:35 eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I might sound greedy but I wanted to get this
00:50:56:a6:4c:35 eth0